# Modeling variable key/object name in response

Tags: swagger

A REST method's JSON response I'm documenting contains an object whose name is variable. For instance, the "processes" object below may contain an "app" or "service" object, depending on the type of process being queried:

```
// Response may contain:
"processes": {
    "app": {
        ...
    }
}

// Or this:
"processes": {
    "service": {
        ...
    }
}
```

What is the recommended way to model this type scenario with Swagger where the key name is not fixed? I looked at `enum` but it seems to be for enumerating possible key values, not key names.

Comment: Need more info. What's the structure of "app" vs "service". Is there an additional field under "processes" that tells the type of response?

Comment: Unfortunately, the structure of "app"s and "service"s are identical, and there are no other fields under "processes".

Comment: Then the only way to describe it is by saying both exist, and yes, it means that theoretically both can be provided.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Relatedly, how about key names that can't be known in advance? For instance, a response that contains a list of objects whose key names are auto-generated UUIDs?

Comment: You can define a general key (map) using `additionalProperties` but you can't control the type. In the future, we may also support `patternedProperties` that would give you additional flexibility in limiting the key.